# Unsure about what this Javascript code do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I'm reading a JS file which has the following code:

```
$('a[href]:not(.no-ajaxy):not([target="_blank"]):not([href^="#"]):not([href^="mailto:"]):not(.comment-edit-link):not(.comments-link):not(#cancel-comment-reply-link):not(.comment-reply-link):not(#toggle-nav):not(.logged-in-as a):not(.add_to_cart_button):not(.section-down-arrow):not([data-filter]):not(.pp):not([rel^="prettyPhoto"]):not(.pretty_photo)').click(function(e){
```

Improved readability

```
$('a[href]:not(.no-ajaxy)
:not([target="_blank"])
:not([href^="#"])
:not([href^="mailto:"])
:not(.comment-edit-link)
:not(.comments-link)
:not(#cancel-comment-reply-link)
:not(.comment-reply-link)
:not(#toggle-nav)
:not(.logged-in-as a)
:not(.add_to_cart_button)
:not(.section-down-arrow)
:not([data-filter])
:not(.pp)
:not([rel^="prettyPhoto"])
:not(.pretty_photo)')
.click(function(e){
```

So, I presume it's a hook that get's attached to all `<a href=...>` links that it's triggered when they are clicked, but it get's excluded in some cases. However I can't seem to understand the following cases:

- `.no-ajaxy` is that a class that get's applied to the `<a class="no-ajaxy">` or it could be applied to a parent element? The same goes for all other not filters starting with `.`
- `rel^="prettyPhoto"` I'd assume it means that if the link is as follows `<a href="..." rel="prettyPhoto">` it wouldn't match this, since it says not this, right?

And I've tried some cases to match those exclusions, but it seems that something is making it ignore those conditions.

Comment: Short answer: select a set of elements and register a click handler.  That is a very long selector, so just start at the beginning and work through it token by token.

Comment: _PS._  instead of assuming, check the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) on the various selectors.

Comment: `no-ajaxy` is a class that comes from the `ajaxify-html.js` plug in. It basically says to not use ajax on the elements with that class. So I think it is applying the hook to all the `<a>` tags that don't have the class `.no-ajaxy`

Comment: I really appreciate the links, although I just started with Javascript and had no idea that it was jQuery selectors. I feel it wasn't needed to hate the question so much just because the question is a newbie one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's all about [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

The code, explained selector by selector:

- `a[href]` all the `<a>` elements that have a `href` attribute and:
- `:not(.no-ajaxy)` doesn't have the CSS class `no-ajaxy`
- `:not([target="_blank"])` doesn't have a `target` attribute valued `_blank`
- `:not([href^="#"])` doesn't have a `href` attribute that starts with `'#'`
- `:not([href^="mailto:"])` doesn't have a `href` attribute that starts with `'mailto:'`
- `:not(.comment-edit-link)` doesn't have the CSS class `comment-edit-link`
- `:not(.comments-link)` doesn't have the CSS class `comments-link`
- `:not(#cancel-comment-reply-link)` doesn't have the ID `cancel-comment-reply-link`
- `:not(.comment-reply-link)` doesn't have the CSS class `comment-reply-link`
- `:not(#toggle-nav)` doesn't have the ID `toggle-nav`
- `:not(.logged-in-as a)` doesn't have a parent node with the CSS class `logged-in-as`
- `:not(.add_to_cart_button)` doesn't have the CSS class `add_to_cart_button`
- `:not(.section-down-arrow)` doesn't have the CSS class `section-down-arrow`
- `:not([data-filter])` doesn't have an attribute `data-filter`
- `:not(.pp)` doesn't have the CSS class `pp`
- `:not([rel^="prettyPhoto"])` doesn't have an attribute `rel` that starts with `'prettyPhoto'`
- `:not(.pretty_photo)'` doesn't have the CSS class `pretty_photo`

So, it gets all the anchor tags with the conditions above, and register `click` event handlers for them.

Comment: Ok, finally in clear words I was able to understand. I much appreciate your help.

Comment: Now, the CSS class is for the `<a>` element right, ignoring parents or children.

Comment: @SHiRKiT yes, only for the element